# How does the return work inside a recursive function in Python?

Tags: python, recursion

I am having issues when returning the values from a recursive function. For example, in a very simple function called 'RBinSearch', I am trying to find the index of the key in an array. Unfortunately, I just cannot able to return the value (answer should be 4) based on my understanding.

For comparison, I have used a normal function with a loop to test the return (in a function called 'BinarySearch' here), which is working as expected. Can anyone please explain how the return behave inside a recursive function and where my understanding is incorrect? Thanks!

```
import math
import sys

def BinarySearch(array, key):
    low=0
    high=len(array)-1
    while(low<=high):
        mid=math.floor((low+high)/2)
        if(key==array[mid]):
            return mid
        elif(key<array[mid]):
            high=mid-1
        elif(key>array[mid]):
            low=mid+1
            
    return -1

def RBinSearch(array,low,high,key):
    if(low<=high):
        mid=math.floor((low+high)/2)
        print("Value of mid: ",mid)
        if(key==array[mid]):
            print("Found the value: ",mid)
            return mid
            sys.exit()
                                   
        elif(key<array[mid]):
            RBinSearch(array, low, mid-1, key)
        else:
            RBinSearch(array, mid+1, high, key)
    return -1
arr=[4,8,10,15,18,21,24,27,29,33,34,37,39,41,43]
print("Index from while Bin search: ",BinarySearch(arr, 18))
print("The index found using the Binary search is: ",RBinSearch(arr, 0,len(arr)-1,18))
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: You use recursion to find the correct spot - and then ignore the result, and `return -1`. You want `return RBinSearch(...)` instead. Also, stylewise, in Python you should use `snake_case` for functions (and variables); `TitleCase` is conventionally used for class names.

Comment: @Amadan Sure, but how to return the result after getting the value in a recursive function? In this example, I would like to return the value of variable 'mid' in RBinSearch but the function keeps returning -1. Why does this happen?

Comment: As I described, and as Ratery answered, but using `return` to pass the subordinate result back. Your terminal invocation returns `mid`, but it returns it only one level up; the intermediate levels were not propagating that value further up. They were returning `-1` instead. tl;dr: The function kept returning -1 because you told it to. :)

Comment: Imagine an analogy, a fire bucket chain. You tell the people "If you're next to the river, fill up the bucket and give it to the next guy. If not, carefully grip the bucket given to you, and yell that you received it." How far do you see water going? Just up to the second guy, because you didn't tell the people away from the river to pass the bucket along.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return `RBinSearch` result in your `RBinSearch` function:

```py
def RBinSearch(array, low, high, key):
    if low <= high:
        mid = math.floor((low + high) / 2)
        print("Value of mid: ", mid)
        if key == array[mid]:
            print("Found the value: ", mid)
            return mid

        elif key < array[mid]:
            return RBinSearch(array, low, mid - 1, key)
        else:
            return RBinSearch(array, mid + 1, high, key)
    return -1
```

Also you shouldn't use `sys.exit()`.